# How to find two values in file and use theese as variables?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep, openwrt

How can I find and store as variables the two numbers followed by `"RX bytes:"` and `"TX bytes:"` in this file? 
I want to calculate with theese values in a simple current bandwidth monitor bash script using an OpenWrt router.

/dev/band1:

```
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
      inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3848954 errors:0 dropped:21234 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4213574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1206316927 (1.1 GiB)  TX bytes:3385060741 (3.1 GiB)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example, the RX bytes, you could:

```
rxBytes=$(yourcmd|grep -Po '(?<=RX bytes:)\d+')
```

replace the RX with TX you get another variable

**EDIT**

you could also go with awk:

```
rxBytes=$(awk -F'RX bytes:' 'NF>1{sub(/ .*$/,"",$2);print $2}')
```

chg the RX  -> TX to get the other one.

Comment: My grep sadly doesn't support pearl style regexp:( Only the extended regexp.

Comment: Or even `set -- $(ifconfig br-lan | grep -Po '(<=[Rt]X bytes:)\d+')`, which should yield RX in `$1` and TX in `$2`, provided the output format doesn't change

Comment: Could this syntax be converted into extended regular expression format? my grep doesn't support the -P switch.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
N=(`ifconfig p2p1 | sed -n 's/.*RX bytes:\([0-9]*\) .*TX bytes:\([0-9]*\).*/\1\n\2/p'`)
echo Bytes received ${N[0]}
echo Bytes sent ${N[1]}
```

This does it with one call to ifconfig, which is probably only important if you want to poll the counters at the same time.

Comment: You can factor out the `grep` into `sed` easily; just add an `-n` option to not print anything by default, and a `p` flag to the substitution to print when it fires.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, I consolidated the grep hack into sed with -n and p flag.